# Scan string for character, print rest of string after the character

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm looking to scan through a string until a specific character is found, then printing the rest of the string after that character is found. Basically if my string is "The quick brown fox" and I search for 'k', I want to print out " brown fox." I've got the code to scan all ready but I'm just stumped on how to advance the pointer to the byte after the delimiter and print from there. Right now it prints everything UP to the delimiter including the character itself and a few junk characters afterwards.

```
    INVOKE Str_length, strVar

    mov edi, strVar
    mov al, find
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF line
    cld
    repne scasb
    jnz NOHIT

HIT:
    cld
    rep movsb
    mov BYTE PTR[edi], 0
    mov edx, OFFSET line
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    ret
```

Obviously my code for the output is wrong I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You don't need to copy anywhere with `rep movsb`: one advantage of 0-terminated strings is that a pointer into the middle of one is also a valid string (that suffix).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I had a feeling I didn't need to include it, and removing it got rid of the random junk characters so that's good

Answer (score 0):

Manged to figure it out, posting for anyone who might have the same problem in the future! Extremely easy solution:

```
    cld
    mov edx, edi
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    ret
```

Since scasb increments the edi until the delimiter is hit, all you need to do is print the edi itself.

Comment: you forgot to include `repne scasb` in your answer >.<.  Also note that [`scasb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd) just does one step and sets FLAGS.  It's only with the the [`repne`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz) prefix that `repne scasb` that repeats while `al != [edi]` and `ECX-- != 0`.